# Swap 350W power supply for 300W power supply

Tags: power-supply

I suspect my power supply has failed and want to test by using another power supply.

Below is the current power supply. Max wattage is 300W.

[image]

The replacement power supply below has a total output of 350W.

[image]

Can I swap a 350W power supply in place of a 300W power supply?

Comment: Basically impossible to say without knowing what components (especially CPU and GPU) your PC uses. Testing for a limited amount of time should be no problem but do not run the PC under full load or for a prolonged amount of time, as overloading a PSU could be a **fire hazard!**

Comment: This pc is using processor intel i7 and built in graphic card.

Comment: @e12345678 - There are literally hundreds of different variations of an i7.

Comment: While I totally agree with @ramhound,you should be OK to test the system on a 300 watt power supply - but you would either want to meter it or provide more component information before using it long term.

Comment: @john While your conclusion may be correct, the limiting factor of computer power supplies are not their voltages, its their current.

Comment: We need clarification if it's a 300W -> 350W swap or the 350W -> 300W. Either way it's probably okay just looking at the numbers, but I don't know the "HEC" brand and IMO anything with "high-quality" in the name should be assumed crap until proven otherwise. For a test it could be okay. In the long run I'd get something from a reputable brand.

Comment: @BlindSpots - The author can [edit] their question instead of the community making what are potentially poor assumptions.

Comment: It seems clear that OP wants to substitute a 350 watt PS for the existing 300 watt one. All else being equal, that should be perfectly ok. But the proposed substitute supply wants 230v @ 50hz, where the original one is ok with 100-127/220-240v. If OP's mains supply is  US standard, I doubt the proposed replacement PS will work.

Comment: We all missed that input voltage mismatch. Good catch @SteveRindsberg.  Interestingly HEC website lists the  [350VN-2RX PSU](https://www.hec-group.com.tw/power_supply/atx12v_v22/index.html#vnrx) as 115V with the [350VP-2RX PSU](https://www.hec-group.com.tw/power_supply/atx12v_v22/index.html#vprx) being the 230V model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at ALL the hardware in the system. PC components should all list their power requirements in their documentation. It is then a pretty simple calculation to see whether your power supply will provide sufficient power. There are even websites that help you calculate this.

This is the only way to know whether your desired replacement will work.

However, there's another calculation you need to consider:

Power supplies that have a higher wattage rating will handle the load of a given set of components more easily, with less wear and thus with better energy "quality" for the components, resulting in better system reliability overall. And, these higher wattage power supplies will still only draw the current required so you're not getting a higher power bill just because you have a larger power supply.

To put it another way: say your current components draw 200 watts total. That is 57% of your old power supply's available current. The lower wattage power supply powering that same of components will experience a load of 66% of its possible current, and this 9% difference will result in more wear on the power supply's internal components.

So my personal recommendation is NOT to go to a lower wattage power supply unless there are other compelling reasons for doing this that outweigh the drawbacks of using a smaller supply.

Comment: Good info.  Answer would be better by focusing on 300 to 350, but valuable to include info about both directions for completeness.