# Do I need a new PSU for my 3060 ti?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

So, my current build uses a 1660, but I am about to upgrade to a 3060 ti. The psu I have now is 500w 80+ gold, I believe it's the thermaltake toughpower gx1, and I am running a ryzen 7 3700x with 32gb of ddr4. Motherboard is a b450 aorus m. From the power consumption specs it seems I should be fine, but I just want to make sure there's nothing I'm overlooking as many sources seem to recommend 650w or higher. Thank you!

Comment: Consider that every fan, drive, LED, RAM module, network or audio card and even the motherboard itself also needs power. Also consider if you want to upgrade anything in the future and if you have any overhead left.

Comment: Have you tried to use a PSU calculator? You should be able to find some using your favorite search engine.

Comment: This may not seem like the answer to your question, but it contains all of the information you need and is the correct answer to your question: https://superuser.com/questions/1755534/swap-350w-power-supply-for-300w-power-supply/1755984#1755984

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap 350W power supply for 300W power supply](https://superuser.com/questions/1755534/swap-350w-power-supply-for-300w-power-supply)

Answer (score 1):

[NVIDIA recommends](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/30-series/rtx-3060-3060ti/)
as "Required System Power" the capacity of 600W, although the
Peak Power Usage of the RTX 3060 Ti is more around 200W.

The total amount that is really required is dependent upon the other
components in the computer.
You could use a PSU Calculator to get a better idea, for example the
[Newegg Power Supply Calculator](https://www.newegg.com/tools/power-supply-calculator/).

When all the calculations are done, better add 100-150W to the number
you get, as a safety measure - the maximal output of a PSU may be
somewhat lower that its advertised capacity.